# how can we display different legends container for same graph(sunburst drill down)? in Amcharts4

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts, amcharts4

I was trying to add two legends containers for the same graph(sunburst drill-down). one on the left side and another on the right side of the graph.

After lots of research, I found the solution but it was for piechart not for sunburst drill down. I want the same solution for sunburst drill down.

Below is the Image of the solution which I found.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oanrx.png)

code for above image:

Js, CSS, HTML

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 *
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 *
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart);

// Add data
chart.data = 
  [{
  "country": "Lithuania",
  "litres": 501.9
}, {
  "country": "Czechia",
  "litres": 301.9
}, {
  "country": "Ireland",
  "litres": 201.1
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "litres": 165.8
}, {
  "country": "Australia",
  "litres": 139.9
}, {
  "country": "Austria",
  "litres": 128.3
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "litres": 99
}, {
  "country": "Belgium",
  "litres": 60
}, {
  "country": "The Netherlands",
  "litres": 50
}];

// Add and configure Series
var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "litres";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "country";
pieSeries.labels.template.disabled = true;

radius = am4core.percent(95);

  chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

      chart.legend.position = "left";
      chart.legend.scrollable = true;

// Create custom legend
chart.events.on("ready", function(event) {
  // populate our custom legend when chart renders
  chart.customLegend = document.getElementById('legend');
  pieSeries.dataItems.each(function(row, i) {
    var color = chart.colors.getIndex(i);
    var percent = Math.round(row.values.value.percent * 100) / 100;
    var value = row.value;
    legend.innerHTML += '<div class="legend-item" id="legend-item-' + i + '" onclick="toggleSlice(' + i + ');" onmouseover="hoverSlice(' + i + ');" onmouseout="blurSlice(' + i + ');" style="color: ' + color + ';"><div class="legend-marker" style="background: ' + color + '"></div>' + row.category + '<div class="legend-value">' + value + ' | ' + percent + '%</div></div>';
  });
});

function toggleSlice(item) {
  var slice = pieSeries.dataItems.getIndex(item);
  if (slice.visible) {
    slice.hide();
  }
  else {
    slice.show();
  }
}

function hoverSlice(item) {
  var slice = pieSeries.slices.getIndex(item);
  slice.isHover = true;
}

function blurSlice(item) {
  var slice = pieSeries.slices.getIndex(item);
  slice.isHover = false;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 530px;
  height: 450px;
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  float: left;
}

#legend {
  width: 200px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}

#legend .legend-item {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#legend .legend-item .legend-value {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 22px;
}

#legend .legend-item .legend-marker {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#legend .legend-item.disabled .legend-marker {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<div id="legend"></div>
```

I tried to solve my problem with the above solution but it didn't work.

Below are the details for my changes :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7rGD.png)

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 * 
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 * 
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// create chart
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4plugins_sunburst.Sunburst);
chart.padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
chart.radius = am4core.percent(98);




data1 = [{
  name: "First",
  children: [
    { name: "A1", value: 100 },
    { name: "A2", value: 60 }
  ]
},
{
  name: "Second",
  children: [
    { name: "B1", value: 135 },
    { name: "B2", value: 98 }
  ]
},
{
  name: "Third",
  children: [
    {
      name: "C1",
      children: [
        { name: "EE1", value: 130 },
        { name: "EE2", value: 87 },
        { name: "EE3", value: 55 }
      ]
    },
    { name: "C2", value: 148 },
    {
      name: "C3", children: [
        { name: "CC1", value: 53 },
        { name: "CC2", value: 30 }
      ]
    },
    { name: "C4", value: 26 }
  ]
},
{
  name: "Fourth",
  children: [
    { name: "D1", value: 415 },
    { name: "D2", value: 148 },
    { name: "D3", value: 89 }
  ]
},
{
  name: "Fifth",
  children: [
    {
      name: "E1",
      children: [
        { name: "EE1", value: 33 },
        { name: "EE2", value: 40 },
        { name: "EE3", value: 89 }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "E2",
      value: 148
    }
  ]
}];


let dt1 = [];
for(var i=0;i<data1.length;i++){
    dt1[i] = {"name":data1[i].name,"fill":"#72A6B2"};
}

chart.data = data1;

chart.colors.step = 2;
chart.fontSize = 11;
chart.innerRadius = am4core.percent(20);

// define data fields
chart.dataFields.value = "value";
chart.dataFields.name = "name";
chart.dataFields.children = "children";


var level0SeriesTemplate = new am4plugins_sunburst.SunburstSeries();
chart.seriesTemplates.setKey("0", level0SeriesTemplate)

// this makes labels to be hidden if they don't fit
level0SeriesTemplate.labels.template.truncate = true;
level0SeriesTemplate.labels.template.hideOversized = true;
level0SeriesTemplate.showOnInit = false;
level0SeriesTemplate.usePercentHack = false;

level0SeriesTemplate.radius = am4core.percent(100);
level0SeriesTemplate.innerRadius = am4core.percent(0);

let selectedState = level0SeriesTemplate.states.create("selected");
selectedState.properties.opacity = 0.7;
level0SeriesTemplate.defaultState.properties.radius = am4core.percent(100);

var currentlySelected;

level0SeriesTemplate.slices.template.events.on("over", function(event) {
  if(event.target.dataItem.sunburstDataItem.children){
   event.target.cursorOverStyle = am4core.MouseCursorStyle.pointer;
  }
})

level0SeriesTemplate.slices.template.events.on("hit", function(event) {
  zoomOutButton.show();
  var hitSlice = event.target;

  if (hitSlice.dataItem.sunburstDataItem.children) {

    var series = event.target.dataItem.component;
    
    if (!series.dummyData) {
      series.tooltip.disabled = true;
      hitSlice.dataItem.label.radius = (hitSlice.radius - hitSlice.pixelInnerRadius) - 7;
      hitSlice.dataItem.label.bent = true;
      hitSlice.dataItem.label.rotation = -180;

      currentlySelected = hitSlice;
      series.dummyData = true;
      series.setState("selected");
      hitSlice.dataItem.sunburstDataItem.series.show();
      series.slices.each(function(slice) {
        if (slice != event.target) {
          slice.dataItem.hide();
        }
      })
    }
    else {
      drillUp(hitSlice);
    }
  }
})


level0SeriesTemplate.labels.template.adapter.add("rotation", function(rotation, target) {
  target.maxWidth = target.dataItem.slice.radius - target.dataItem.slice.innerRadius - 10;
  target.maxHeight = Math.abs(target.dataItem.slice.arc * (target.dataItem.slice.innerRadius + target.dataItem.slice.radius) / 2 * am4core.math.RADIANS);
  return rotation;
})

var level1SeriesTemplate = level0SeriesTemplate.clone();
level1SeriesTemplate.hidden = true;
level1SeriesTemplate.innerRadius = am4core.percent(10);
chart.seriesTemplates.setKey("1", level1SeriesTemplate)
level1SeriesTemplate.fillOpacity = 0.75;

var level2SeriesTemplate = level0SeriesTemplate.clone();
level2SeriesTemplate.hidden = true;
level2SeriesTemplate.innerRadius = am4core.percent(20);
chart.seriesTemplates.setKey("2", level2SeriesTemplate)

level0SeriesTemplate.hiddenInLegend = false;
level1SeriesTemplate.hiddenInLegend = true;
level2SeriesTemplate.hiddenInLegend = true;

var zoomOutButton = chart.seriesContainer.createChild(am4core.ZoomOutButton);
zoomOutButton.visible = false;
zoomOutButton.horizontalCenter = "middle";
zoomOutButton.verticalCenter = "middle";
zoomOutButton.events.on("hit", function() {
  drillUp(currentlySelected)
})


function drillUp(slice) {
  collapse(slice);
  var series = slice.dataItem.component;
  series.tooltip.disabled = false;
  series.dummyData = false;
  series.setState("default");

  series.slices.each(function(slice) {
    if (slice != event.target) {
      slice.dataItem.show();
    }
  })

  if (series.parentDataItem.seriesDataItem) {
    currentlySelected = series.parentDataItem.seriesDataItem.slice;
  }
  else {
    zoomOutButton.hide();
  }
}


function collapse(slice) {

  slice.dataItem.label.bent = false;
  slice.dataItem.label.radius = 10;


  if (slice.dataItem.sunburstDataItem.children) {
    slice.dataItem.sunburstDataItem.children.each(function(child) {
      child.seriesDataItem.component.setState("hidden");
      collapse(child.seriesDataItem.slice);
    })
  }
}

/* var legend = new am4charts.Legend();
legend.position = "right";
legend.scrollable = true;
legend.parent = chart.chartContainer;
legend.background.fill = am4core.color("#000");
legend.background.fillOpacity = 0.05;
legend.width = 120;
legend.align = "right";
legend.data = dt1; */
/* 
[{
  "name": "2016",
  "fill":"#72A6B2"
}, {
  "name": "2017",
  "fill": "#667E93"
}, {
  "name": "2018",
  "fill": "#488BB2"
}];*/
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

//chart.legend.parent = chart.chartContainer;
//chart.legend.itemContainers.template.togglable = true;
chart.legend.position = "left";
chart.legend.scrollable = true; 



// Create custom legend
chart.events.on("ready", function(event) {
  // populate our custom legend when chart renders
  chart.customLegend = document.getElementById('legend');
  /* level0SeriesTemplate.slices.dataItems.each(function(row, i) { */
  level0SeriesTemplate.dataItems.each(function(row, i) {
    var color = chart.colors.getIndex(i);
    var percent = Math.round(row.values.value.percent * 100) / 100;
    var value = row.value;
    legend.innerHTML += '<div class="legend-item" id="legend-item-' + i + '" onclick="toggleSlice(' + i + ');" onmouseover="hoverSlice(' + i + ');" onmouseout="blurSlice(' + i + ');" style="color: ' + color + ';"><div class="legend-marker" style="background: ' + color + '"></div>' + row.name + '<div class="legend-value">' + value + ' | ' + percent + '%</div></div>';
  });
});

function toggleSlice(item) {
  var slice = level0SeriesTemplate.dataItems.getIndex(item);
  if (slice.visible) {
    slice.hide();
  }
  else {
    slice.show();
  }
}

function hoverSlice(item) {
  var slice = level0SeriesTemplate.slices.getIndex(item);
  slice.isHover = true;
}

function blurSlice(item) {
  var slice = level0SeriesTemplate.slices.getIndex(item);
  slice.isHover = false;
}

/* var legendContainer = am4core.create("legend", am4core.Container);
legendContainer.width = am4core.percent(100);
legendContainer.height = am4core.percent(100);

legend = new am4charts.Legend();
legend.parent = legendContainer;
legend.position = "middle";
legend.valign = "middle";
legend.data = dt1;
legend.scrollable = true;

   let Label1 = legendContainer.createChild(am4core.Label);
    //Label1.height = 50;
    Label1.fontWeight = "600";
    Label1.align = "left";
    Label1.paddingTop = 6;
    Label1.paddingBottom = 6;
    Label1.text = "Non-Reco Analytics"; */
 
/*
chart.legend.data = [{
  "name": "2016",
  "fill":"#72A6B2"
}, {
  "name": "2017",
  "fill": "#667E93"
}, {
  "name": "2018",
  "fill": "#488BB2"
}]; */
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 530px;
  height: 450px;
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  float: left;
}

#legend {
  width: 200px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}

#legend .legend-item {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#legend .legend-item .legend-value {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-left: 22px;
}

#legend .legend-item .legend-marker {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#legend .legend-item.disabled .legend-marker {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/sunburst.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<div id="legend"></div>
```

objective: I want legends for the 1st layer of the sunburst on the right side and the 2nd layer on the left side of the chart.

I hope you get enough understanding of my problem.